# URL encode a name in java

Tags: java, urlencode

I want to URL encode a name in java including the double quotes also but it is omitting the double quote from the name.

e.g.

```
String name = "abc";
String url = URLEncode(name,"UTF-8");
System.out.println(url);
```

it is printing

```
abc
```

but i want the url as

```
%22abc%22
```

I searched on net but did not get anything.

Comment: The question doesn't have anything to do with URL encoding by itself.  It should be more like "how to put double quotes in Strings".  How to escape them (using a backslash) is explained in the java language specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html (3.10.6).

Comment: So, the title is wrong and the `urlencode` tag shouldn't be there.  
Such elementary questions are just not interesting which is probably why it got downvoted twice.

Comment: @herman anyway thanks a lot for replying with correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

In that case you shall write `String name = "\"abc\"";`

Answer (score 3):

That's because your 'name' doesn't include the double-quotes. What you want is:

```
String name = "\"abc\"";
```

Now your name contains double quotes: "abc"

Answer (score 2):

`%22` refers to doublequotes (`"`) in URL encoding. so, you need to add it in your URL String. In order to add doublequotes in Java String. You need to escape it by backslash (`\`)

```
String name = "\"abc\"";
```

to expect the encoded URL as `%22abc%22`

Answer (score 1):

The double quote isn't part of the `name` string.  If you want it to be, use

```
String name = "\"abc\"";
```

If you don't want the `name` variable to include the quotes, but you do want them to be added to the URL encoding, use

```
String url = URLEncode("\"" + name+ "\"","UTF-8");
```